# Apache mod_proxy+mod_rewrite = "Request exceeded the limit ..." error

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Good day,

I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy for my Tornado app which runs on `http://localhost:8090`. I want Apache to proxy everything that arrives to /api/v2 through HTTPS to `http://localhost:8090`.
Apache is also takes care of authentication, thus I need to forward the authenticated user name to my Tornado app. Hence using `mod_rewrite`.

I've added the following entry to Apache config:

```
<Location "/api/v2">
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8090

    # Next four lines are to set X-Forwarded-User
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}]
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-User %{RU}e

    SSLRequireSSL

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "My site"
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal pwauth
    Require valid-user

    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

This works wonders, except that I see the following error in my Apache log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable confguration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I've enabled the debug log for mod rewrite and I see indeed a strange thing - it looks like the rewrite happens 10 times in loop piling the request onto itself:

```
172.16.0.150 - admin [29/Jan/2014:19:01:06 +0200] [sm397/sid#7f8452235588][rid#7f840c0093b8/initial] (3) [perdir /api/v2/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'proxy:http://localhost:8090/'
172.16.0.150 - admin [29/Jan/2014:19:01:06 +0200] [sm397/sid#7f8452235588][rid#7f840c01f638/subreq] (3) [perdir /api/v2/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/'
172.16.0.150 - admin [29/Jan/2014:19:01:06 +0200] [sm397/sid#7f8452235588][rid#7f840c00d6a8/subreq] (3) [perdir /api/v2/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/'
172.16.0.150 - admin [29/Jan/2014:19:01:06 +0200] [sm397/sid#7f8452235588][rid#7f840c025e08/subreq] (3) [perdir /api/v2/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/'
172.16.0.150 - admin [29/Jan/2014:19:01:06 +0200] [sm397/sid#7f8452235588][rid#7f840c029e28/subreq] (3) [perdir /api/v2/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/'
172.16.0.150 - admin [29/Jan/2014:19:01:06 +0200] [sm397/sid#7f8452235588][rid#7f840c02de48/subreq] (3) [perdir /api/v2/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/proxy:http://localhost:8090/'
```

Full log here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HqnuFFpQ

How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's very strange, as there shouldn't be anything causing the appending on the subrequests.

Let's see if anything changes when that rule isn't applied to the insane subrequests by adding an `NS` flag:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER},NS]
```

Comment: A lot of changes indeed! Now it works correctly! Thyank you so much. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bTQ6rPUB  Seems like one needs to read mod_rewrite manual over and over again until there is a solution :)